# Unset array item of class static property seems to not work

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, class, static

I try to write a plugin for WordPress, that keep into array some posts. This array it is contained inside a static property of a class.

The class is like the following:

```
class my_class_name
{
    private static $posts = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('template_redirect',   array($this, 'get_posts'));
    }

    public function get_posts()
    {
        $args     = array(...);
        $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        $my_posts =   isset($my_posts->posts) && !empty($my_posts->posts) ? $my_posts->posts : array();

        my_class_name::$posts = $my_posts;
    }

    public static function get_posts()
    {
        return my_class_name::$posts;
    }

    public static function unset_post($item_id)
    {
        unset(my_class_name::$posts[$item_id]);
    }
}

$class_instance = new my_class_name();
```

And then in my theme I have the following code:

```
$my_posts    =   my_class_name::get_posts();

if(!empty($my_posts))
{
    $key    =   array_rand($my_posts, 1);
    $post   =   $my_posts[$key];
    my_class_name::unset_post($key);   // I have try this way
    unset($dynamic_banners[$key]);     // as well this way too

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($my_posts);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

But the problem is that the array with the given ID still exists in my array. Am I doing something wrong ?

Is there any solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are pass-by-value in PHP, so `$my_posts` is not the same as the `my_class_name::$posts` variable.  You have to unset the values in it separately:

```
$key    =   array_rand($my_posts, 1);
$post   =   $my_posts[$key];
my_class_name::unset_post($key);
unset($my_posts[$key]);
```

Alternatively, you can do pass-by-reference by declaring `get_posts` as

```
public static function &get_posts()
```

and then doing

```
$my_posts = &my_class_name::get_posts();
```

Comment: I have also try to retrieve the valies by reference, and still the same issue. in example : $my_posts =& my_class_name::get_posts();

Comment: [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) say to declare the method as `public static function &get_posts()` as well as doing `$my_posts =& my_class_name::get_posts();` to do referencing.